# error substracting two date numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, date

Im using matlab and I have the following problem. I have two date vectors:

```
A{1,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';

A{2,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';

A{3,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';

A{4,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';

A{5,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';
```

And

```
B{1,1} = '24-02-2011 23:57:36';

B{2,1} = '24-02-2011 23:48:44';

B{3,1} = '24-02-2011 23:59:42';

B{4,1} = '24-02-2011 23:59:16';

B{5,1} = '24-02-2011 23:59:00';
```

After turning them into numbers using datenum, I get the next results:

**For vector A **

```
11539.0024537037

11539.0024537037

11539.0024537037

11539.0024537037

11539.0024537037
```

**For vector B**

```
11174.9983333333

11174.9921759259

11174.9997916667

11174.9994907407

11174.9993055556
```

**A-B equals**

```
364.004120370371

364.010277777779

364.002662037037

364.002962962964

364.003148148149
```

The problem is that after subtracting A from B, the result is not a difference between 4 and 15 minutes give or take, but of a day, and I suppose that the problem is that the dates are in different days but very close to each other, still I don’t know how to fix it.

Comment: please provide the code that you used to transform the vectors.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want? Before posting a question on stackoverflow please see the documentation of MATLAB. if I am not mistaken you just basically did datenum(A)-datenum(B) without caring how the data was organized.

CODE:

```
A{1,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';
A{2,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';
A{3,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';
A{4,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';
A{5,1} = '25-02-2011 0:03:32';
date_a=datenum(A, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')

B{1,1} = '24-02-2011 23:57:36';
B{2,1} = '24-02-2011 23:48:44';
B{3,1} = '24-02-2011 23:59:42';
B{4,1} = '24-02-2011 23:59:16';
B{5,1} = '24-02-2011 23:59:00';
date_b=datenum(B, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS')

date_a-date_b
(date_a-date_b)*24*60
```

OUTPUT:

```
ans =

    0.0041
    0.0103
    0.0027
    0.0030
    0.0031


ans =

    5.9333
   14.8000
    3.8333
    4.2667
    4.5333
```

Comment: An extra tip: When using datenum, it helps to test by immediately using datestr.  In this case, `datestr(datenum('25-02-2011 0:03:32'))` returns some nonsense.